# Empty Portals and PortalAlias table after installing DNN on Windows Vista

Tags: dotnetnuke, failed-installation

After installing version 5.02.02 on `localhost:81` as a new installation (which didn't run smooth but OK'ed in the end), the following error came up when opening the site:

> `Domain Name Windows Vista Does Not Exist In The Database`

My guess is that the installer doesn't like `http://localhost:81` or any other port. After checking the *Portals* and *PortalAlias* tables, both came up empty.

- Is there a way to fill these settings interactively?
- If not, how should I fill them by hand and what dependencies should I watch out for? In short: what values go where?
- <strike>If not, would it help to reinstall to a mapped domain name (via windows hosts file) on a normal port?</strike> EDIT: no, it didn't help

I'm not certain the error's due to the different port. It seems as though DNN tries to map the local machines domain name and wants to fill it in in the Portals table, but doesn't because `localhost` doesn't match `mymachine.example.host`.

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer. I had a similar issue after cloning/duplicating my DNN instance, and decided to [post them seperately](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26143589/419956) (linking here just in case it may help someone else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user [Brent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278361/brent) actually answered this question, but later deleted his own answer. Since it is the correct answer, I repeat it here:

#### Answer by [Brent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278361/brent):

> I was having the same problem and
>   found a solution.
>
> 1. Login as Host, and add a Portal Alias under "Admin > Site Setting"
> 2. In web.config uncomment:    `<add key="UsePortNumber" value="true" />`
> 3. Restart the app in IIS Manager.
>
> Details of the solution are in this [Geeks with Blogs blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/02/19/119788.aspx).

NOTE: In addition to this, it is still necessary to add the portal and the portalalias by hand. After adding them by hand, restart the web application (touch web.config, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the errors like this are result of permission/configuration problems, I would recommend to try creating a new website by following [this article](http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/DNN4_DevelopmentEnvironment/DNNDevelopmentWindowsVista.htm). Hopefully that will help you a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, this was not the case, no permission errors here.