# Duplicated DNN7 installation and now getting "Domain Name xyz Does Not Exist In The Database"

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a DNN7 installation running on my local machine. This is for development purposes, and I wanted to use IIS instead of Cassini for this. The app is bound to HTTP port 81. All is working well, even though the `UsePortNumber` appsetting is *not* turned on.

All is well. Now I wanted to clone my setup to do some experiments. Here are the steps I took:

1. Duplicated the website folder.
2. Created a new IIS app pointing to that folder, bound to port 82.
3. Duplicated the DotNetNuke7 database.

However, when I try to access my site I get this error:

> Domain Name xyz Does Not Exist In The Database

With an entire explanation following that message.

My situation and issue are similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2207801/419956). I've tried the solution mentioned there, but adding the `UsePortNumber` appSetting didn't work. I didn't expect it to work at any rate, since my regular instance is already running on a nonstandard port (81), and it's working fine.

So I figured perhaps port 81 is still mentioned somewhere in a file perhaps, so I used Powershell to do this:

```powershell
dir *.* -recurse | select-string ":81" | select-object -unique
```

But nothing relevant came up.

So something is different in my scenario from the other question, but I can't seem to figure out what. Anyone got a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably forgotton one or two of these steps:

First, don't forget to change the connection string, e.g.:

```xml
  <add name="SiteSqlServer" 
       connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Database=DotNetNuke7Clone;User=somebody;Password=something" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Or the appSetting:

```xml
  <add key="SiteSqlServer" 
       value="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DotNetNuke7Experiments;User ID=sa;Password=HagelBaksteen77!"/>
```

Second, update the portal alias table, e.g.:

```sql
UPDATE PortalAlias SET HTTPAlias = REPLACE(HTTPAlias, ':81', ':82')
UPDATE PortalSettings SET SettingValue = REPLACE(SettingValue, ':81', ':82')
```

Comment: What if all of above are not working and still getting same error ?

Comment: Then you should either (a) find out yourself what happened and post your solution as an answer here, or (b) ask a new SO question referring to this one and explaining how your situation is different. (I'm afraid my question is two years old, and I can hardly help you on your scenario anymore, let alone without more details. Sorry.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have already posted question on stack but I was trying to get answer here if there's any other situation you have encountered. I'll definitely post here if I found solution